# Resizing a window before new contents are displayed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow

My app has a Preferences window. When the user switches tabs in this window, `windowDidResize:` is called. How can I resize the window before its contents will be displayed?

Comment: Do you mean the window *should* resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `[window setFrame ...]` before invoking `[[window contentView] addSubview: view];`.

Comment: In my window i use NSTabView and i don't understand how to use [[window contentView] addSubview: view];